# How do I upgrade equipment past 3 stars?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

I had several 1 star Boomerangs. I leveled up and combined them into a max level-3 star boomerang. Is there a way to get it all the way up to 5 stars? Or is 3 stars the max for an item that started at 1? It shows up in the "combine equipment" list with the note "LvlMx" but I definitely have another boomerang to use. I even have another 3 star boomerang to combine it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only combine weapons/armor to up their level cap twice - so a 1 star item can only ever be a 3 star item when maxed out.  That's what "LvMAX" means on the "Combine Equipment" screen - you've used your two combine operations on that item, and it's maxed out.

Also note that it's not required to level up or combine the item to be sacrificed.  You can combine a maxed out 2-star boomerang with a freshly dropped, level 1, 1-star boomerang to make a 3-star boomerang.

Comment: So basically I am free to sell all of the other boomerangs I have found. That's good to know.

Comment: @Reafexus, as a side note, my suggestion to you is to avoid combining items that are less than say, 3 or 4 stars to start with.  I've found that gear that starts at 3-5 stars gets much stronger than combined 1 and 2 star items very quickly.  If you've got the gil to spare, you can combine items till you're blue in the face, but if you're light on cash you might save it.

Comment: I understand. It's just the irrational digital hoarder talking lol